# Why typing :(){ :|: & };: and pressing enter on my Ubuntu machine's terminal freezes the system?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, malware

Friend suggested to type `:(){ :|: & };:` and pres enter on my Ubuntu machine's terminal and I did, it gave me output as number and system hanged forever. Could anyone help me understand why did this happen?

Answer (score 2):

This is a fork bomb, there are plenty of information about this on the web:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991142/how-does-this-bash-fork-bomb-work